# IBM Bluemix PostgreSQL and psql

Tags: php, postgresql, mysqli, ibm-cloud

I've created a PHP runtime enviroment in Bluemix and attached a postgresql server to it.
When trying to use psql from terminal, it doesn't seem to can reach the database?

Also, adding `./bp-config/options.json` and:

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
}
```

I'm not able to conncet via mysqli from my php scripts.

Comment: Where is the psotgresql server located? Which terminal? Could you add some more details?

Answer (score 3):

The extension mysqli for PHP is useful to connect to a MySQL database server.
As you described you bound to your application a PostgreSQL database, so this extension is completely useless.
To connect to a PostgreSQL you could use composer dependency manager (supported on Bluemix) with you PHP application and set your composer.json with the dependency. You can obviously add other dependencies to your composer.json.

```
   "require": {
        "ext-pgsql": "*"
   }
```

Then you could connect to your PostgreSQL service using a code like the following one in order to get service credentials from VCAP_SERVICES variables available from CloudFoundry

```
if (getenv("VCAP_SERVICES")===false) {
$db = 'XXXX';
define("APP_DB_SCHEMA", $db);
define("APP_DB_HOST", 'xxxx');
define("APP_DB_PORT", "xxxx");
define("APP_DB_USERNAME", 'xxxx');
define("APP_DB_PASSWORD", "xxxx");

} else {

// getting VCAP configuration
$services = getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
$services_json = json_decode($services, true);
$pgsql_config = $services_json["postgresql-9.1"][0]["credentials"];

define("APP_DB_SCHEMA", $pgsql_config["name"]);
define("APP_DB_HOST", $pgsql_config["host"]);
define("APP_DB_PORT", $pgsql_config["port"]);
define("APP_DB_USERNAME", $pgsql_config["user"]);
define("APP_DB_PASSWORD", $pgsql_config["password"]);
}
```

and then establish the DB connection through:

```
$dbConnectionString = "host=" . APP_DB_HOST . " port=" . APP_DB_PORT . " dbname=" . APP_DB_SCHEMA . " user=" . APP_DB_USERNAME . " password=" . APP_DB_PASSWORD;
$dbConnection = pg_connect($dbConnectionString);
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I of course got "require": { "ext-pgsql": "*" } in composer.json. But I cannot build it, I get BuildpackCompileFailed

Comment: Which buildpack are you using when pushing?

Comment: I don't know? The standard? And shouldn't I be able to use psql in terminal?

Comment: Could you please provide some details about:
- how your are pushing your application (through cf cli)
- the log of your application running cf logs [application-name] --logs

Comment: I get asked wether the server is running or not. That's why I would like to login via psql in the terminal to actually see the database. Should that be possible or is it only accesible via my PHP runtime enviroment in Bluemix?

Comment: You cannot connect to PostgreSQL service instance from outside Bluemix.
Here you can find the documentation regarding PostgreSQL service experimental:
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/PostgreSQL/index.html

The best way to check which could be the error or the problem is getting the application's logs, through CF clit (with the command I already posted) or (worst) using the Bluemix UI
Are you using CF cli with your application? I guess yes, at least to push your application